# C# Nmath to Python SciPy

Tags: c#, python, scipy, nmath

I need to port some functions from C# to Python, but i can't implement next code right:

```
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None)]
public static SqlDouble LogNormDist(double probability, double mean, double stddev)
{
    LognormalDistribution lnd = new LognormalDistribution(mean,stddev);
    return (SqlDouble)lnd.CDF(probability);
}
```

This code uses CenterSpace Nmath library.

Anyone can help me to write a right function in python, which will be similar to this code?

Sorry for my English.

**UPD** Actually, i don't understand which scipy.stats.lognorm.cdf attrs are simillar to C# probability, mean, stddev

If just copy existing order to python, like in answer below, i get wrong number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scipy has a bunch of distributions defined in the scipy.stats package

```
import scipy.stats

def LogNormDist(prob, mean=0, stddev=1):
    return scipy.stats.lognorm.cdf(prob,stddev,mean)
```

#### Update

Okay, it looks like Scipy's stat definitions are a little nonstandard. Here's the end of the docstring for `scipy.stats.lognormal`

> Lognormal distribution
>
> lognorm.pdf(x,s) = 1/(s*x*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-1/2*(log(x)/s)**2)
>      for x > 0, s > 0.
>
> If log x is normally distributed with mean mu and variance sigma**2,
>      then x is log-normally distributed with shape paramter sigma and scale
>      parameter exp(mu).

So maybe try

```
return scipy.stats.lognorm.cdf(prob,stddev,scipy.exp(mean))
```

If that still doesn't work, try getting a few sample points and I'll see if I can find a working relationship.

#### Udpate 2

Oops, I didn't realize that the scale param is a keyword. This one should now work:

```
import scipy.stats

def LogNormDist(prob, mean=0, stddev=1):
    return scipy.stats.lognorm.cdf(prob,stddev,scale=scipy.exp(mean))
```

Cheers and good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't work, so i've run C# code with different attributes and this is what i have:
prob  | stddev  |   mean  | result
0.3   |   1.0   |   3.2   | 5,31431365968782E-06
0.8   |   2.3   |   7.0   | 0,000843306609677019
0.1   |   0.2   |   0.3   | 0
1     |   4.1   |   6.8   | 0,0486046047161232

Answer (score 2):

The Python docs describe a method random.lognormvariate(mu, sigma):

http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Maybe that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Python.NET (this is *NOT* IronPython), it allows to access .NET components and services:

http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I use Python.NET with Python 2.6 (had to build it myself).
It's somewhat unstable, lacks .NET 3.0, and it seems the project is inactive for quite some time.
I would not recommend it for production code, but it's quite nice to have .NET components handy from Python.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan,

We've got no interest in keeping people locked into NMath. Here's what we're doing in NMath.

```
  double t = ( Math.Log( x ) - mu_ ) / sigmaRoot2_;
  return ( 0.5 + 0.5 * Erf( t ) );
```

where

```
private static double Erf( double x )
{
  return ( x < 0.0 ? -StatsFunctions.IncompleteGamma( 0.5, x * x ) : StatsFunctions.IncompleteGamma( 0.5, x * x ) );
}
```

That should help...

- Trevor